Proof that $Pr(\omega_i) = (1/2)^i$ defines a valid probability distribution on a countably infinite sample space
My approach:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^i &= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{i+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^i \\
&= \frac{1/2}{1 - 1/2} = 1 \quad 
\end{align*}
Using the geometric series formula $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a \cdot r^i = \frac{a}{1 - r}$
But is that really a sound proof? The upper bound of the sum is technically $\infty - 1$ and can this expression always just be reduced to $\infty$ in such a case?
Thanks!

What step do you doubt? $\infty-1$ is not a number, and it is not an upper bound on anything. It certainly is n9t "technically" anything.
